# reading external server file in jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery

i need to load an external  html page in my codes

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#check").load("http://www.mysite.com/names.html")});
```

and i need my script reads this external html page

is it possible to do such a thing in **jquery or even in php  ?!**

i need to know all of the possible ways .

Answer (score 0):

Using .ajax instead of .load

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.mysite.com/names.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    //Do some thing with html
  }
});
```

See more:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol - From the page you linked.

Answer (score 0):

If the page you require access to resides on an external server then you will have to proxy it via your local server using curl.  [Demo and Documentation here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)  You then make your AJAX call to your curl page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what about using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) on PHP side and returning it to the page via Ajax?